# Scala: What is :: in { case x :: y :: _ => y}? Method or case class?

Tags: scala

```
object Test1 extends App {
    val list: List[Int] => Int = {
        case x :: y :: _ => y    //what is ::? method or case class?
    }
    println(list(List(1, 2, 3)))    //result is 2.
}
```

I set "syntax coloring" in scala IDE, foreground color of *method* I set Red. code snapshot:
[image]
And I can't open declaration of **black ::**, so I don't know what it is.

If **black ::** is method, it should be called by this way:

```
... {case _.::(y).::(x) => y}     //compile failed!
```

So, What is **black ::**? method or case class?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it's a method as described [here](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/working-with-lists.html#i-986649610-1). For history's sake, in case that page goes away, here's the blurb:

> About pattern matching on Lists
>
> If you review the possible forms of patterns explained in Chapter 15,
>   you might find that neither List(...) nor :: looks like it fits one of
>   the kinds of patterns defined there. In fact, List(...) is an instance
>   of a library-defined extractor pattern. Such patterns will be treated
>   in Chapter 24. The "cons" pattern x :: xs is a special case of an
>   infix operation pattern. You know already that, when seen as an
>   expression, an infix operation is equivalent to a method call. For
>   patterns, the rules are different: When seen as a pattern, an infix
>   operation such as p op q is equivalent to op(p, q). That is, the infix
>   operator op is treated as a constructor pattern. In particular, a cons
>   pattern such as x :: xs is treated as ::(x, xs). This hints that there
>   should be a class named :: that corresponds to the pattern
>   constructor. Indeed there is such as class. It is named scala.:: and
>   is exactly the class that builds non-empty lists. So :: exists twice
>   in Scala, once as a name of a class in package scala, and again as a
>   method in class List. The effect of the method :: is to produce an
>   instance of the class scala.::. You'll find out more details about how
>   the List class is implemented in Chapter 22.

So it's scala.::(a,b)

Comment: Thank you very much! I got it!

Comment: That's the case class `::`. There its `.unapply` is used in infix syntax, which can be done for any case class whose name starts with appropriate symbol character (e.g. Anorm `case class ~[A, B](a: A, b: B)` used in row parser [pattern matching](http://cchantep.github.io/anorm/#using-pattern-matching)).

Comment: @cchantep Exactly! **::** is a case class really! Thank you for your answer!

Comment: @cchantep Your reply is very helpful for me! Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Here Sequence pattern is applied.

### case x :: y :: _ => y

means, the passed sequence first value is mapped to x and second value is mapped to y and all remaining values are applied with wildcard pattern (_).

Here finally the case returns y means second value.

### another ex: case x :: y :: z :: _ => z

this case returns third element from the sequence.

### another ex: case _ :: _ :: z :: _ => z

in this example first and second element are used underscore as we don't need THESE elements hence replaced with _.

Also it throws Exception if the passing list size is less than what it expects, for Example the below throws exception:

```
val third: List[Int] => Int = {case _ :: _ :: z :: _ => z}

third(List(1, 2))
```